# Google reCaptcha Javascript validation

Tags: javascript, validation, recaptcha

I'm having a problem with reCaptcha validation.

I want to validate the reCaptcha V2 in JavaScript to identify a special case that isn't processed correctly on the server-side validation (and no, there is no way for me to change the server-side validation).  This way I can display a message informing the user that his form post won't be accepted...

I asked about the original problem here, but I have no solution for now: [Google reCaptcha: Unable to validate in time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58138707/google-recaptcha-unable-to-validate-in-time), I will not fix the original problem, I want a workaround to display a message when the Captcha returns a specific value.

How do I identify in JS the following reCaptcha response:

> REQ_PARAM_NAME::validated-captcha
>   REQ_PARAM_VALUE::Pair(false,Unable to validate in time. Response is assumed correct. 101781)

What are the properties available in the Captcha response objet that will allow me to identity one specific rejection reason "Unable to validate in time...".

Comment: This is not the right way to bump another question. Please include your code, just like the other question , also - if needed - tag the question as salesforce too

Comment: This is a new question related to the same problem.  There is no code yet, I am asking how to write the JS to perform the validation.

Comment: This might help: http://form.guide/snippets/google-recaptcha-javascript-validation.html

Comment: What I am missing is how to find the response message to identify one specific rejection type "Unable to validate in time".  What are the properties available in the object response?